# What program can I use to make a tree of a language family?

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-families, resource-request

I'm not looking to make anything really special looking, I'd just like to make basic branches going down to draw a family tree. I tried Paint but that's difficult to edit, and Word wouldn't be easy to make into an image.
I'm hoping to find out what those in linguistics who make historical trees normally use.

[image: semitic language tree]
<sub>(source: [oocities.org](http://www.oocities.org/dtmcbride/reference/classification/images/semitic_lang_tree.gif))</sub>

Comment: Languages don't normally have family trees, though language families do. Are you asking about syntax trees? Can you [edit] this to show a picture of what you're asking about please?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited to the Software Recommendations stackexchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns programs for drawing certain kinds of charts and does not concern linguistics..

Comment: Till today, I still find a suitable software like this which can intergrate with Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd also recommend qTree - if you've ever sat in a syntax class or had to work with natural language parsers, it will be very easy to use:

http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf

Answer (score 10):

If your want a user-friendly program to use on the go you can check [Cmaptool](http://cmap.ihmc.us/) from good people at the Florida Institute for Human & Machine Cognition (IHMC) it's really easy to use straight forward and you can export your data to variety of extensions.

[image]

If you TeX you can use [qTree](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/qtree/) package from CTAN.

```
\Tree[.IP [.NP [.Det \textit{the} ]
           [.N\1 [.N \textit{package} ]]]
      [.I\1 [.I \textsc{3sg.Pres} ]
            [.VP [.V\1 [.V \textit{is} ]
                       [.AP [.Deg \textit{really} ]
                            [.A\1 [.A \textit{simple} ]
                                  \qroof{\textit{to use}}.CP ]]]]]]
```

The above code (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex)) will produce the below:

`(Although it is used to make syntax trees but still you could use it for Language family trees)`

[image]